# Regex in Javascript to trim links

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I want to add css class to  links (using Javascript) that match begining of link. My links are currently looking like that:

```
http://localhost/MainApp/User/UserEdit.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1
```

And I want to check out only the part before id: `/MainApp/User/UserEdit.aspx`

I already have function that is adding css class to links and it looks like that:

```
function markActiveLink() {    
        var path = location.pathname;
        var home = "/";
        $("a[href='" + [path || home] + "']").parents("li").each(function () {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
    }
```

value of location.pathname is /MainApp/User/UserEdit.aspx

**Question:** How can I modify my function markActiveLink() so that it will mark links even with id after main part of link?

Any help here much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector instead of exact selector for href attribute.

Change:

```
 $("a[href='" + [path || home] + "']")
```

to

```
 $("a[href^='" + [path || home] + "']")
```

To address issue with the home path selecting all the links change the makeActiveLink to as follows:

```
function markActiveLink() {             
    var path = location.pathname;         
    var links = null;
    if(path){
        links = $("a[href^='" + path  + "']");
    } else {
        links = $("a[href='/']");
    }
    links.parents("li").each(function () {             
        $(this).addClass("selected");         
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that it is the best solution, but you could use the contains selector:

```
$("a[href*='" + [path || home] + "']")
```